# Specify multiple provisioning profile for expo local credentials

Tags: expo

Expo EAS has a way to use [local credentials](https://docs.expo.dev/app-signing/local-credentials/)

The problem is that I have 2 environments: production and development, and 2 provision profile accordingly. Unfortunatly I can't find a way how to define 2 different provision profiles in `credentials.json`.

```
{
  "android": {
    "keystore": {
      "keystorePath": "android/keystores/release.keystore",
      "keystorePassword": "paofohlooZ9e",
      "keyAlias": "keyalias",
      "keyPassword": "aew1Geuthoev"
    }
  },
  "ios": {
    "provisioningProfilePath": "ios/certs/profile.mobileprovision",
    "distributionCertificate": {
      "path": "ios/certs/dist-cert.p12",
      "password": "iex3shi9Lohl"
    }
  }
}
```

The only field we have here is `provisioningProfilePath`.
When I'm trying to build internal distribution with a production profile, of course, I'm getting the error: `You must use an adhoc provisioning profile (target 'TARGET NAME)' for internal distribution any solution?`

Any suggestions?